# Do I need to always specify the opening <html> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html

First Form:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
     <title>Untitled</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
     <body>

     </body>
 </html>
```

Second Form:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Untitled</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
     <body>

     </body>
 </html>
```

As I know including `<!DOCTYPE html>` (if using HTML5) before `<html>` tag is mandatory, otherwise I may face behaviour issues in my website. (I was told [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107728/what-will-happen-if-i-dont-include-the-html-doctype-tag))

In the first one, there is no start of `</html>` tag, but I have included it in the second one.

I have noticed some of the websites use one of these complexion. It maybe with `<html>` or non `<html>`! Even a HTML editor Android app (WebMaster) uses the first one (with no `<html>`)!

I can't understand, is the `<!DOCTYPE html>` exact same as `<html>`, just attached with `!DOCTYPE`, or both are different!

So, which one is correct? And why that one is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Doctype is mandatory and completely different to the `html` start tag.

(The Doctype has `html` in it because XML and SGML doctypes must specify the tag name of the root element, and the HTML 5 Doctype is designed to be backwards compatible with browsers that expected one).

---

The start and end tags for the `html`, `head`, and `body` elements are optional.

For example, the HTML specification has this to say about [the `html` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element):

> Tag omission in text/html:
>
> - An html element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.
> - An html element's end tag can be omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.

You'll find similar rules for `head` and `body` (as well as some other elements).

This is true for every version of HTML (but not for XHTML which doesn't allow any tag to be omitted).

You only need to include the start tag if you want to include an attribute on it. In general, it is a good thing to state the language your document is written in so best practise is to have an explicit `html` start tag with a `lang` attribute.

Comment: @Santi — You are incorrect. The `html` start is is optional. The element is still opened. The end tag *can* also be omitted, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: If I'm reading this right your saying they're both valid (which is news to me also) in which case the question is "What is the correct format?" I think your saying both but I'm not 100% clear

Comment: Aside from `href=""` which is common to both, both are valid HTML. Which is correct depends on how you measure correctness. Validity is a reasonable measure.

Comment: Here's the reference from w3c for those interested, https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#optional-tags ...not that I was checking your work @Quentin :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, in HTML5 only `!DOCTYPE` and `title` tags are mandatory. All other tags are optional and only for the developer convenience and readability.

For more, you can read Google's Styleguide for HTML & CSS: https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Optional_Tags

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Quentin's and Maciek's answers, `<!DOCTYPE html>` declares an HTML file or stream as having the `html` document type and top-level element to SGML parsers. SGML (Standard Generalized Markup Language) is the generalization and origin of HTML, XML, and other markup languages. HTML5 and later don't anymore reference the SGML standard (ISO 8879) to describe validity and parsing rules for HTML. Nevertheless, HTML documents are in fact SGML documents and can be fully parsed using SGML, including W3C HTML5, W3C HTML5.1, WHATWG HTML, and all other versions of HTML.

The SGML standard also defines the rules for tag omission, or rather describes the rules for inferring tags that aren't actually there in an HTML document, and treat the document as if they were. SGML being merely a language framework for describing concrete markup languages such as HTML, the rules for tag omission must be told to SGML as SGML has no build-in, hardcoded knowledge about HTML. This is a way to tell SGML that the `html` start- and end-element can be omitted in a document (note the additional SGML declaration syntax is *not* supported by web browsers directly!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ELEMENT html O O (head,body?)>
    <!-- other declarations for
         the head and body element
         following here ... -->
]>
```

This declaration for the `html` element has the `O O` (double letter O for **O**mission), with space between) tag omission indicators telling SGML that the start- and the end-element tags can be omitted, respectively. If a `-` hyphen had been used in place of `O` as either the start- or end-tag omission indicator, or both, the respective tag is made required instead.

There are additional HTML elements which admit tag inference stated in the various HTML5 specifications. I've created a transcription of these and other grammar rules into SGML for modern HTML at my project page for it ([2](http://sgmljs.net/docs/html5.html)).

For example, in the above declaration for the `html` element, the `(head,body?)` part declares that the child content of `html` must be a `head` element, followed by an optional `body` element. Since these, too, are declared optional (though not in the above snippet for space reasons), in combination with further declarations for `title`, a complete and valid HTML document can look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Hello</title>
<p>Body Text
```

How this is parsed using SGML is described in my linked project page ([3](http://sgmljs.net/docs/html5.html#tag-omission-on-document-level-elements)), as well as in the slides/talk I gave about it ([1](http://sgmljs.net/blog/blog1701.html)).

Answer (score -2):

You will only need the first line  TAG and a TITLE tag. Head tag and everything else on the page is optional, technically speaking